# Could we use static method outside class in java

Tags: java

I define a static method `f` for class named `a` in java,

Could I also use it as `a.f` outside the class?

OR we could only use it as a help function within the class?

Comment: Please post what you tried so far.

Comment: If it's `public`, or package-private and you're in the same package.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: Also note that with reflection you can access mostly anything, even private methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...could I also use it as a.f outside the class?

Yes. You can use the static method if it is declared as `public`:

```
public static void f() {
    // ...
}
```

or if it is *package-private* (no modifier):

```
static void f() {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If that is a `public static` method, you can use it from anywhere outside the class.

If that is package-private (default), then you can use only it within that package.

Answer (score 1):

Marking the method `Public` will make it accessible wherever you want.

Marking the method `Protected` will make it accessible in same package and also in subclasses
Marking the method nothing that is keeping it `default` (no modifier)will make it visible inside same package

Wherever u try to access your method Just make sure that your class is also visible there!

Hope this helps!
All the best