# Spring Security circular bean dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, vaadin, spring-jdbc

I'm currently working on a Vaadin spring application. According to the app specifications, authentication/authorization of the users must be completed by querying database via `jdbcTemplate`. How to solve this issue? I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE.

**UPDATE**: This approach works with Spring Boot 1.1.x.RELEASE, however on the latest versions of it produces following error message.

```
Description:
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:
┌─────┐
|  jdbcAccountRepository defined in file [repositories\JdbcAccountRepository.class]
↑     ↓
|  securityConfiguration.WebSecurityConfig (field services.JdbcUserDetailsServicessecurity.SecurityConfiguration$WebSecurityConfig.userDetailsService)
↑     ↓
|  jdbcUserDetailsServices (field repositories.JdbcAccountRepository services.JdbcUserDetailsServices.repository)
└─────┘
```

The original code looks like this:

AccountRepository:

```
public interface AccountRepository {
    void createAccount(Account user) throws UsernameAlreadyInUseException;
    Account findAccountByUsername(String username);
}
```

JdbcAccountRepository:

```
@Repository
public class JdbcAccountRepository implements AccountRepository {

    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public JdbcAccountRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void createAccount(Account user) throws UsernameAlreadyInUseException {
        try {
            jdbcTemplate.update(
                "insert into Account (firstName, lastName, username, password, role) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                user.getFirstName(),
                user.getLastName(),
                user.getUsername(),
                passwordEncoder.encode(
                        user.getPassword()),
                        user.getRole()
            );
        } catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {
            throw new UsernameAlreadyInUseException(user.getUsername());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Account findAccountByUsername(String username) {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
            "select username, password, firstName, lastName, role from Account where username = ?",
            (rs, rowNum) -> new Account(
                    rs.getString("username"),
                    rs.getString("password"),
                    rs.getString("firstName"),
                    rs.getString("lastName"),
                    rs.getString("role")),
            username
        );
    }
}
```

JdbcUserDetailsServices:

```
@Service
public class JdbcUserDetailsServices implements UserDetailsService {
    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    JdbcAccountRepository repository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        try {
            Account account = repository.findAccountByUsername(username);
            User user = new User(
                account.getUsername(),
                account.getPassword(),
                AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(
                        account.getRole()
                )
            );
            return user;
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            LOGGER.debug("Account not found", e);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

SecurityConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    VaadinSecurity security;

    @Bean
    public PreAuthorizeSpringViewProviderAccessDelegate preAuthorizeSpringViewProviderAccessDelegate() {
        return new PreAuthorizeSpringViewProviderAccessDelegate(security, context);
    }

    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true,prePostEnabled = true)
    public static class GlobalMethodSecurity extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

        @Bean
        @Override
        protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
            return super.accessDecisionManager();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public static class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        JdbcUserDetailsServices userDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        DataSource dataSource;

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
        }

        @Bean
        public TextEncryptor textEncryptor() {
            return Encryptors.noOpText();
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
         * #configure(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity)
         */
        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            //Ignoring static resources
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/VAADIN/**");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        }

        @Bean(name="authenticationManager")
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
         * #configure(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity)
         */
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/"))
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                    .and()
                .csrf().disable();
        }
    }
}
```

P.S If downgrade Spring Boot version to [1.1.5,1.2.0) , this problem will not occur ( due to other dependency, I must to use the latest)

Comment: You are not using the (DataSource dataSource) in your configuration, why inject ??

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You could replace [constructor-based dependency injection](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-constructor-injection) with [setter-based dependency injection](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-setter-injection) to resolve the cycle, see [Spring Framework Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-dependency-resolution):

> **Circular dependencies**
>
> If you use predominantly constructor injection, it is possible to create an unresolvable circular dependency scenario.
>
> For example: Class A requires an instance of class B through constructor injection, and class B requires an instance of class A through constructor injection. If you configure beans for classes A and B to be injected into each other, the Spring IoC container detects this circular reference at runtime, and throws a `BeanCurrentlyInCreationException`.
>
> One possible solution is to edit the source code of some classes to be configured by setters rather than constructors. Alternatively, avoid constructor injection and use setter injection only. In other words, although it is not recommended, you can configure circular dependencies with setter injection.
>
> Unlike the typical case (with no circular dependencies), a circular dependency between bean A and bean B forces one of the beans to be injected into the other prior to being fully initialized itself (a classic chicken/egg scenario).

Comment: I had the same issue and used setter injection. However, circular dependency problem continued existing

Comment: I  have solved this problem by converting construction injections to field injections

Comment: In case you are using Lombok, do remove "@AllArgsConstructor".
This also enforces constructor injections.

Answer (score 42):

I prefer the `@Lazy` method. That way I can stick to one pattern.

See http://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring

Comment: You should mention in your answer, that this solution only works, if it is possible to create a proxy (Java proxy or CGLIB proxy) of the dependent object.

Comment: Fun fact: In the very article you referenced it says at paragraph [5. In Conclusion](https://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring#Conclusion) and I quote 'The preferred method is using setter injections.'
But thanks for the link in the first place!

Answer (score 26):

Your `PasswordEncoder` bean definition is in `WebSecurityConfig` which needs `JdbcUserDetailsServices`. `JdbcUserDetailsServices` again is dependent on `JdbcAccountRepository` which needs `PasswordEncoder`. So the cycle forms. A simple solution is to take out the `PasswordEncoder` bean definition out of `WebSecurityConfig`. Even inside `SecurityConfiguration` class will solve the cyclic problem.

Comment: Cleanest solution in the thread imo

Answer (score 9):

From Zeeshan answer:

> Your PasswordEncoder bean definition is in WebSecurityConfig which needs JdbcUserDetailsServices. JdbcUserDetailsServices again is dependent on JdbcAccountRepository which needs PasswordEncoder. So the cycle forms. A simple solution is to take out the PasswordEncoder bean definition out of WebSecurityConfig. Even inside SecurityConfiguration class will solve the cyclic problem.

Another simple suggestion would be to change PasswordEncoder definition to public static from public only:

```
@Bean(name = "passwordEncoder")
public PasswordEncoder passwordencoder() {
    return new CustomPasswordEncoder();
}
```

To:

```
@Bean(name = "passwordEncoder")
public static PasswordEncoder passwordencoder() {
    return new CustomPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Comment: Why does changing the PasswordENcoder to static solve the problem ?

Comment: @HelloWorld https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22829186/could-we-use-static-method-outside-class-in-java#:~:text=If%20that%20is%20a%20public,only%20it%20within%20that%20package. basically a static method doesn't need instantiation

Comment: @HelloWorld https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/361893/instantiating-vs-injection when you inject something you are saving on instantiation of object and when you declare a method as static it kind of becomes outside of the standard instantiated object & u can call directly calls stattic method in a class by something like SomeClass.StaticMethod(doSomething)

Comment: @VH very interesting thanks for answering my question in comment!

Comment: @HelloWorld no worries, typically `classA` has `a function` that `classB` is in need of and `classA` also needs something that `classB` has so in effect they are both injecting one another and you end up in circular motion. The best solution would be to remove that `function of interest` in `classA` to `classC` and then inject `classC` in `classB` as well as continuing to inject `classA`. `classA` can also inject `classC` if it needs the `function` too. This removes the circular issue

Answer (score 7):

I used `@Lazy` in the constructor of one class and it solved my problem:

```java
public class AService {  
    private BService b;   
    public ApplicantService(@NonNull @Lazy BService b) {    
        this.b = b;  
    }
}  

public class BService {  
    private AService a;   
    public ApplicantService(@NonNull BService a) {  
        this.a = a;  
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

@Zeeshan Adnan is right. Taking the `PasswordEncoder` out of `WebSecurityConfig` solves the **Cyclic dependency problem**.

Answer (score 1):

As for Spring boot 3.0.x: as stated before, it can be solved by removing the `PasswordEncoder` to an external bean (out of your `SecurityConfiguration` bean).

E.g.

```
@Configuration
public class PasswordEncoderConfig {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

And than autowire it wherever needed (e.g. in your SecurityConfig):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    ...
    ...
    
    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    ...
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a separate config class for PasswordEncoder and then import it in securityconfig class and it resolve my problem.
SourceCode here with spring boot latest -> **https://github.com/juyelhushen/JWT-springboot-3-Latest.git**

Answer (score -1):

One of the solution is don't use constructor. For exaple instead of:

```
private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Autowired
public JdbcAccountRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
}
```

You can use:

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
```

Comment: I am aware of this approach, but for some reason compiler throws out NoBeanException sometimes. Which is why it forces to find a new, better way of defining it.

Comment: field injection is not recommended