# dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle

Tags: spring, spring-boot, datasource

I am having three classes A,B,C and connecting to database in each class with data source.
Class A

```
 public class A(){
     @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSourceA;

    @Bean
        @Primary
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.ds")
        public DataSource DataSourcePGStreet() {
            return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        }


        .../code here 

    dataSourceA.getConnection();


    }
```

Class B

```
 public class B(){
    @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSourceB;
    .../

    dataSourceB.getConnection();

    }
```

Class C

```
public class C(){
@Autowired
    private DataSource dataSourceC;
.../code here 

dataSourceC.getConnection();



}




***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

|  dataSourceA
      |
   dataSourceB
      |
   dataSourceC

      |
      |
└─────┘
```

But the above application throws a some of the beans in the application context form a cycle error which I do not why.Any help is appreciated

Comment: put the full stack trace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Security circular bean dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40695893/spring-security-circular-bean-dependency)