# Spring Security unresolvable circular reference

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

With this project I wanted to implement a Jwt authorization with Spring Boot for a rest api webservice, but it keeps giving me this:

```
2021-12-09 18:42:12.284  WARN 98229 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

And this stacktrace:

```
2021-12-09 18:42:12.331 ERROR 98229 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:355) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:410) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:362) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:334) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at jac.rosani.calendar.configuration.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ee51f5aa.bCryptPasswordEncoder(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at jac.rosani.calendar.configuration.SecurityConfig.configureGlobal(SecurityConfig.java:72) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:724) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at jac.rosani.calendar.CalendarApplication.main(CalendarApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
```

I tried every solution i could find both here on stack overflow like the ones listed here [Spring Security circular bean dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40695893/spring-security-circular-bean-dependency), but none of them seem to work, since it keeps giving me the same error.

Here's my code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http = http.cors().and().csrf().disable();

        http = http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and();

        http = http
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(
                        (request, response, ex) -> {
                            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, ex.getMessage());
                        })
                .and();

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/auth").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return authenticationManager();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

```
@Controller
public class JwtAuthenticationController {

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    @PostMapping(path = "/auth", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> createAuthenticationToken(
            @RequestBody JwtAuthenticationReqDto authenticationRequest)
            throws Exception {

        authenticate(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword());

        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
        final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(responseBuilder(token));
    }

    private Map<String, String> responseBuilder(String token) {
        Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<String, String>(1) {
            {
                put("token", token);
            }
        };

        return response;
    }

    private void authenticate(String username, String password) throws Exception {

        authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
    }

}
```

```
@Component
@Getter
@Setter
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;

        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {

            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring("Bearer ".length());
            try {
                username = getJwtTokenUtil().getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                throw new ServletException("Unable to get JWT Token", e);
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                throw new ServletException("JWT Token has expired", e);
            }
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

            UserDetails userDetails = this.getJwtUserDetailsService().loadUserByUsername(username);

            if (getJwtTokenUtil().validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());

                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

```
@Service
public class UserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = repo.findByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }

        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
        // String roles = user.getRoles();
        // String[] tokens = roles.split(";");
        // for(String role : tokens) {
        // grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        // }
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_DETAIL"));
        // grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_EDIT"));
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(),
                grantedAuthorities);
    }
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    public User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Any idea on what I could do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The security config requires the filter which requires the token util created by the config. Just implement the `configure(HttpSecurity)` somewhere else so you can remove the config's dependency on the filter.